# How do you drop an in use database in Azure Sql Managed Instance?

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-managed-instance

When we ran Sql Server in a virtual machine we were able to use the following sql to drop in use databases.

```
use master
ALTER DATABASE [TargetDatabase] set single_user with rollback immediate;
Drop database [TargetDatabase]
```

According to the [Managed Instance Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-managed-instance-transact-sql-information#configuration) and our testing `set single_user` is not supported.  Is there an alternative way to drop in use databases?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend doing it using powershell. That is more efficient and goes through checks

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.sql/remove-azsqlinstancedatabase?view=azps-3.5.0

Remove-AzSqlInstanceDatabase -InstanceName '' -ResourceGroupName '' -Name '' -Verbose

Comment: Per your suggestion I removed the database from `Azure Managed Instance`, using `PowerShell` and it worked great. Thanks for sharing your thoughts.